# Compare List with Value in Dart / Flutter

Tags: dart, flutter

I am trying to compare an input value to a list of items in Dart language, however, it does not seem to work.

Method:

```
  String validateStoreNumber(String value) {

    List<String> storeList = ['55', '56', '88'];

    // String patttern = r'(^[a-zA-Z ]*$)';
    RegExp regExp = new RegExp(r'^[+-]?([0-9]+([.][0-9]*)?|[.][0-9]+)$');
    if (value.length == 0) {
      return "car number is required";
    } else if (!regExp.hasMatch(value)) {
      return "Accepts only numbers";
    } else if (value.length != 2){

      return "car number must have 2 digits";
    } else if (value != storeList.contains(value)){

      return "Not our model";
    }
    return null;
  }
```

Comment: What is the input and what is the expected output? What does "does not seem to work" mean?

Comment: This line `} else if (value != storeList.contains(value)){` looks odd. I'd expect it to be `} else if (!storeList.contains(value)){` or similar. What is this code supposed to do?

Comment: That is a validation method. I have a form that takes an input (value in this case), validates it and then takes the user to another screen. I am trying to get this input and compare it against a hard coded list of numbers as in storeList ?

Comment: That worked, actually ! Thanks.

Comment: So that was the whole problem? Or only a part of it?

Comment: That was the whole problem. But now it works, Dart syntax is a little bit different that what I am used to. Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This line...

```
else if (value != storeList.contains(value))
```

Is the problem.  The left side "value" is a string, and the right side "contains" is a boolean.  You are comparing a string to a boolean.

I think you want this...

```
else if (!storeList.contains(value))
```

Comment: Thanks, correct answer has been provided by Günter Zöchbauer, but you added explanation as well.